# C++ Debugger tool shows verbose details of variable in VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am debugging a C++ project in VSCode. Yet the debugger tool shows too much internal detail about the variable, while I just want to see the value of the `string`. Take a `string` as an example

[image: snapshot of a string]

Also, in the `Debug->VARIABLES->Locals` zone on the left panel of the editor, my local variables are not added, where they should be auo-displayed.

[image: Local variables not show]

Related configuration files:

1. `task.json` ---
   My `task.json` is pretty verbose so I won't post all of its content. But essentially I complie the project with `g++ -O0`
2. `launch.json` --- Basically it lanuches the program with `gdb`

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C/C++: clang++ build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

3. `c_cpp_properties.json` --- I think most important options are `compileCommands` and `configurationProvider`

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/deps",
                "${workspaceFolder}/srcs"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "compileCommands": "${workspaceFolder}/compile_commands.json",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode-cpptools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

4. `compile_commands.json` --- It's pretty long, here is a snippet.

```
{
        "directory": "/mnt/e/code/chinapp",
        "arguments": [
            "g++",
            "-g",
            "-std=c++17",
            "-fPIC",
            "-O0",
            "-Wfatal-errors",
            "-Werror",
            "-Wall",
            "-Wextra",
            "-Weffc++",
            "-pedantic",
            "-pedantic-errors",
            "-Wshadow",
            "-Wconversion",
            "-Wfloat-equal",
            "-Wold-style-cast",
            "-Woverloaded-virtual",
            "-MF",
            "/mnt/e/code/chinapp/build/%mnt%e%code%chinapp%srcs%chinapp.d",
            "-MT",
            "/mnt/e/code/chinapp/build/%mnt%e%code%chinapp%srcs%chinapp.o",
            "-c",
            "/mnt/e/code/chinapp/srcs/chinapp.cpp",
            "-o",
            "/mnt/e/code/chinapp/build/%mnt%e%code%chinapp%srcs%chinapp.o",
            "-pthread",
            "-I",
            "/mnt/e/code/chinapp/deps",
            "-I",
            "/mnt/e/code/chinapp/srcs",
            "-finline-limit=1600",
            "-D",
            "ASSERT_ENABLE=1"
        ],
        "file": "/mnt/e/code/chinapp/srcs/chinapp.cpp"
    }
```

1. How to fix the problem?
2. Why does this happen? The project used to work fine.
3. How to avoid it in the future.

Comment: strings are implemented different in each library/compiler, you would complain that it would not work for compiler X that you use, `config_path` is **not** a local variable

Comment: you should use a build tool if you have >1 cpp file

Comment: But why is the string displayed in that ugly way? It used to only show the chars in the string instead of the who object. What casued this?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following configuration to `lauch.json` fixed the problem.

```
"setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            },
            {
                "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
```

But I don't quite understand what `setupCommand` is used for, hope someone could elobrate that.